# Python (3.5) - Constructing String to Save File - String Contains Escape Characters

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am using Python (3.5) to loop through some .msg files, extract data from them, which contains a url to download a file and a folder that the file should go into. I have successfully extracted the data from the .msg file but now when I try to piece together the absolute file path for the downloaded file, the format ends up weird, with backslashes and \t\r.

Here's a shortened view of the code:

```
for file in files:
    file_abs_path = script_dir + '/' + file
    print(file_abs_path)

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(file_abs_path)

    pattern = re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<=\n))[^:<\n]*[:<]\s*([^>\n]*)', flags=re.DOTALL)
    results = pattern.findall(msg.Body)

    # results[0] -> eventID
    regexID = re.compile(r'^[^\/\s]*', flags=re.DOTALL)
    filtered = regexID.findall(results[0])
    eventID = filtered[0]
    # print(eventID)

    # results[1] -> title
    title = results[1].translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)).replace(' ', '_') #results[1]
    title = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    title = title.decode('UTF-8')
    #results[1]
    print(title)

    # results[2] -> account
    regexAcc = re.compile(r'^[^\(\s]*', flags=re.DOTALL)
    filtered = regexAcc.findall(results[2])
    account = filtered[0]
    account = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', account).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    account = account.decode('UTF-8')
    # print(account)

    # results[3] -> downloadURL
    downloadURL = results[3]
    # print(downloadURL)
    rel_path = account + '/' + eventID + '_' + title + '.mp4'
    rel_path = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', rel_path).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    rel_path = rel_path.decode('UTF-8')
    filename_abs_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
    # Download .mp4 from a url and save it locally under `file_name`:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(downloadURL) as response, open(filename_abs_path, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

    # print item [ID - Title] when done
    print('[Complete] ' + eventID + ' - ' + title)

    del outlook, msg
```

So as you can see I have some regex that extracts 4 pieces of data from the .msg. Then I have to go through each one and do some further fine tuning, but then have what I need:

```
eventID
# 123456

title 
# Name_of_item_with_underscord_no_punctuation 

account
# nameofaccount

downloadURL
# http://download.com/basicurlandfile.mp4
```

So this is the data I get, and I've `print()` it off and it doesn't have any weird characters. But when I try to construct the path for the .mp4 (filename and directory):

```
downloadURL = results[3]
# print(downloadURL)
rel_path = account + '/' + eventID + '_' + title + '.mp4'
rel_path = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', rel_path).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
rel_path = rel_path.decode('UTF-8')
filename_abs_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
# Download .mp4 from a url and save it locally under `file_name`:
with urllib.request.urlopen(downloadURL) as response, open(filename_abs_path, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

After doing this, the output I get from running the code is:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "sfaScript.py", line 65, in <module> with urllib.request.urlopen(downloadURL) as response, open(filename_abs_path, 'wb') as out_file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/Kenny/Desktop/sfa_kenny_batch_1\\accountnamehere/123456_Name_of_item_with_underscord_no_punctuation\t\r.mp4'`

**TL;DR - QUESTION**

So the `filename_abs_path` somehow got changed to 
`C:/Users/Kenny/Desktop/sfa_kenny_batch_1\\accountnamehere/123456_Name_of_item_with_underscord_no_punctuation\t\r.mp4`

I need it to be

`C:/Users/Kenny/Desktop/sfa_kenny_batch_1/accountnamehere/123456_Name_of_item_with_underscord_no_punctuation.mp4`

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: You can always just do a `str.replace('\t','')` and `str.replace('\r','')` at the end. What do you get when you try it with different files, with different path names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your regex captured a tabulation char (`\t`) and a linefeed char (`\r`) in `title`

A quickfix for this would be:

```
title  = title.strip()
```

(before composing the filename)

which removes all "blank" chars, including tabulations and carriage return chars.

Comment: Wow, so simple. It worked perfectly. Do you think that I even need to do the `unicodedata.normalize` and `title.decode`?

Comment: frankly, I dunno. If there are strange accents or such, maybe. Doesn't hurt to leave it in. Make a test without as well... I can't tell, I don't have your data.